# COMMIT within a PostgreSQL function fails

Tags: postgresql, function, loops, transactions, commit

I would like to generate test data this way:

```
create table test.persons (
id serial primary key,
first_name varchar,
last_name varchar
);

create or replace function test.generate_persons() returns void as $$
begin 
for x in 1..10 loop
    for y in 1..10 loop
        insert into test.persons (first_name, last_name) values (
            'max',
            'meier'
        );  
    end loop;
    commit;
end loop;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

select test.generate_persons()
```

But get the error "invalid transaction termination". Why?

Comment: That's correct behavior, you can only commit in a procedure. Not a function. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-transactions.html

Comment: means doing commit in a procedure, and call this procedure from a function should work, right?

Comment: ok, thx. Found some more information about this and understand every function breaks transaction control and is not possible to use in this manner therefore.

Comment: What do you mean with `every function breaks transaction control`? The only thing you can't do in a function, is starting or committing a transaction. You can use savepoints, exception handling, etc. etc. You can also wrap multiple function calls into a procedure.